# Splitted words from string serialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

How can I serialize a string like this: `"Yes,No"` into something like this `{"0":"Yes", "1":"No"}` ?

I have split the string by `','` and I've stored value into a `KeyValuePair<int,string>`. After serialization, the result is something like this:

`{"Key" : "0" , "Value" : "Yes"},{"Key":"1","Value":"No"}`

Comment: You don't really want to do that, because in javascript (and c#) you can't declare a variable named "0" or "1", which is what you're asking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = yourString.Split(',').Select((v, k) => new { k, v, })
    .ToDictionary(a => a.k, a => a.v);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the final result you're asking for you could do this:

```
String.Join(",", input.Split(',')
                 .Select((s,i) => "{\"Key\":\""+i+"\",\"Value\":\""+s+"\"}"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always just serialize it yourself:

```
string theString = "True,False";
var result = theString.Split(',')
                      .Select((v, i) => string.Format("\"{0}\":\"{1}\"", i, v));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "yes,no";
var d  = s.Split(',');
var result = new Dictionary<int,string>(){};
for (int i = 0; i < d.Length; i++) {
   result.Add(i, d[i]);
}
```